# Ember update API url within Route from search field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm wondering if i can update the API URL that i Have in a Route from an search field?

```
App.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(ishav) {
    return $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='+ishav.name+'&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json').then(function(data){
        console.log(data.artist)
        return data.artist
    })
}
});
```

Instead of the `ishav.name` I want to get the name from the search field.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do it. The part that is missing from the code you provided is where this would happen. From a view, you would redirect to a route and pass that term as a parameter.

In the view, you can bind your input field

```
{{input class="search-query" type="search"}}
```

On your controller you will do something when that changes:

```
search: function (val) {
  this.transitionToRoute(App.ArtistRoute, val);
}.property()
```

Then on your route you can simply use the name.

**Extra**

To avoid unnecessary network request, I would introduce only transition within a [debounce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce) function (to ensure this is only called once):

```
search: function (val) {      
  Ember.run.debounce(this.searchArtist, val, 500);
}.property(),
searchArtist: function (name) {
  this.transitionToRoute(App.ArtistRoute, name);
}
```